# How to plot yearly dataset using pandas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I want to plot line graph of yearly usage of {a, b} pairs.

X axis should be year, and y axis should be usage.

Here is my dataset.

```
a   b       year    usage   
a2  10104   2011    7.292787
a0  10104   2012    43.545533
b0  12011   2009    96.130359
b1  12011   2009    7.658487
b1  14102   2010    6.975572
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pivot_table` to rearrange data such that I have combinations of `a` and `b` in the columns and `year` in the index.

However, there may be missing data once we've pivoted.  By using `interpolate` with the `index` parameter, we fill in missing data with the interpolated values while maintaining proportionality with the relative changes in the index value.  This matters when the index values are not uniformly separated, eg `[2005, 2006, 2008]`.  If the index is uniformly separated, then using `index` will not harm as it would be the same as the default.

```
d1 = df.pivot_table('usage', 'year', ['a', 'b']).interpolate('index')
d1.index = pd.PeriodIndex(d1.index, freq='A')
d1.plot()
```

[image]

---

**Response to @jezrael's comments**

It is beneficial to observe what the data looks like without `interpolate`

```
d1 = df.pivot_table('usage', 'year', ['a', 'b'])
d1.index = pd.PeriodIndex(d1.index, freq='A')
d1

a            a0        a2         b0        b1          
b         10104     10104      12011     12011     14102
year                                                    
2009        NaN       NaN  96.130359  7.658487       NaN
2010        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN  6.975572
2011        NaN  7.292787        NaN       NaN       NaN
2012  43.545533       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
```

In this case, we don't see what could happen.  But I imagined that there was much more data where we'd see gaps of `NaN` between sparse data.  Instead of forward filling, we can fill proportionately.

```
d1 = df.pivot_table('usage', 'year', ['a', 'b']).interpolate('index')
d1.index = pd.PeriodIndex(d1.index, freq='A')
d1

a            a0        a2         b0        b1          
b         10104     10104      12011     12011     14102
year                                                    
2009        NaN       NaN  96.130359  7.658487       NaN
2010        NaN       NaN  96.130359  7.658487  6.975572
2011        NaN  7.292787  96.130359  7.658487  6.975572
2012  43.545533  7.292787  96.130359  7.658487  6.975572
```

Now again, this would show its benefit only with more data.  As with this data, we only get to observe limited forward filling.

---

*Regarding `mean`*
Note that I use `pivot_table` and one of the things `pivot_table` handles is if there are duplicates within the `index/column` specification.  It will aggregate all values that fall into that cell with the `aggfunc`.  By default that function is `mean`.  However, in this case, per the data that has been presented, there are no duplicate `a/b/year` combinations.  As such, no aggregation took place.

Comment: Great! But my x-axis(year) shows "0.0 0.5 1.0 ... +2.009e3". How can I change it to display year?

Comment: Thanks. you save my data!

Comment: @jezrael I appreciate you encouraging me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use if no duplicates in pairs `a, b` vs `year`:

```
s = df.set_index(['year','a','b'])['usage']
      .unstack([1,2])
      .sort_‌​index(axis=1)
      .interpolate('index')
s.index = s.index.astype(str)
s.plot()
```

Comment: But, there are a lot of {a, b} pairs. Shouldn't I apply groupby or something?

Comment: Yes, sure, but do you need count of pair with years? like `df.groupby('year')['a','b'].size().plot()` ?